# Configurador rgpd, política de cookies - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, cookies

Estoy intentando hacer un módulo que pueda configurar las cookies del sitio según solicita la ley.

El problema que nunca e trabajado con cookies y no se como `activar/desactivar` la cookies. De momento he creado un modal que cuando abre o bien puedes darle a configurar o tiene un botón de aceptar todas. Si le das a configurar te salen tres opciones.

1)Cookies de funcionamiento.
Este no se puede desactivar, ya que se necesita para funcionar bien el sitio.

2)Cookies de estadísticas.
Este solo lleva 3 cookies, `_ga`, `_gat`, `_gid` que son de Analytics.

3)Cookies de Marketing.
En este caso no tengo ningúna.

El modal está así:

```
<div class="modal fade modalCook" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content posiModalCoo">
        
        <img src="{{ asset('images/logo/logo.svg') }}" class="logoCookies">
        <div class="modalCookies">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/slider/humoStaticoBlanco.png') }}" alt="High As" class="humoEstaModal">
            <div class="indexModal">
                <div id="principal">
                    <div class="center">
                        <h1>Configuración de cookies</h1>
                        <p>Las cookies son importantes para ti, influyen en tu experiencia de navegación. Usamos cookies analíticas, de personalización y publicitarias (propias y de terceros) para hacer perfiles basados en hábitos de navegación y mostrarte contenido personalizado. Puedes consultar nuestra <a href="{{ route('app.cookies') }}">Política de cookies</a>. Al hacer click en "Aceptar", consientes que todas las cookies se guarden en tu dispositivo o puedes configurarlas o rechazar su uso pulsando en "Configurar".</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center posBtnCookies">
                        <a class="btnModalCookie" id="configurar">Configurar</a>
                        <a href="" class="btnModalCookie aceptaCookie">Aceptar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="configuracion" style="display: none;" style="position: relative;">
                    <span class="closeConfig" id="cerrarConfiguracion"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                    <div class="center">
                        <h1>Panel de configuración de cookies</h1>
                        <p>Este es el configurador avanzado de cookies propias y de terceros. Aquí puedes modificar parámetros que afectarán directamente a tu experiencia de navegación en esta web.</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <h2>Cookies de funcionamiento</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis nam similique cum eius. Nostrum mollitia laborum consequuntur deserunt vel non explicabo fugiat.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 offset-xl-1">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches">
                                <label class="switch ">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="info" name="funcionamiento" checked disabled>
                                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-9">
                            <h2>Cookies de estadísticas</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis nam similique cum eius. Nostrum mollitia laborum consequuntur deserunt vel non explicabo fugiat.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 offset-xl-1">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches">
                                <label class="switch ">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="info" name="estadistica">
                                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-9">
                            <h2>Cookies de Marketing</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis nam similique cum eius. Nostrum mollitia laborum consequuntur deserunt vel non explicabo fugiat.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 offset-xl-1">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches">
                                <label class="switch ">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="info" name="marketing">
                                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="margenBotsConfig">
                        <a id="permiteTodas" class="permiteTodas">Permitir todas y continuar</a>
                        <a href="" class="btnModalCookie aceptaCookie pull-right" style="margin: 0px;">Guardar configuración</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="{{ asset('images/slider/humoStatico2Blanco.png') }}" alt="High As" class="humoStatico2Modal">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si os dais cuenta hay dos apartados en el mismo modal, es el mensaje inicial y el configurar. Lo muestro y oculto del siguiente modo si le dan al configurar o cierran el configurar.

```
$("#configurar" ).click(function() {
   $('#principal').css("display","none");
   $('#configuracion').css("display","block");
});

$("#cerrarConfiguracion" ).click(function() {
   $('#principal').css("display","block");
   $('#configuracion').css("display","none");
});
```

Pero aquí llega mi problema, realmente solo tengo que poder quitar o poner las cookies de analitica, y si ya a dado a aceptar guardar esto en una cookie, pero no se como proceder, he leido mucho y no comprendo la verdad.

Me podeis guiar? no busco la solución pero si comprender... gracias

**Edición**

He conseguido con laravel deshabilitar cookies que yo creo de este modo:

Deshabilitar:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('nameCookie'));
```

Añadir:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cookieName', 'value', $minutes));
```

Pero no se como habilitar y deshabilitar las de google `_ga, _gat, _gid`

Luego he encontrado esto:

```
window['ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'] = true;
```

Si lo pones en true, Analytics no hace rastreo.
Pero com hago que cuando le de a un botón, guarde esa configuración en una cookie?? Y es posible cambiar ese estado con javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que encontre una solución.

Si le da al primer botón que pone **aceptar** realizamos lo siguiente.

```
//Si acepta todo activamos track que es la que activa analytics y aceptaCookies que es la que guarda que no muestre de nuevo el modal//
$("#AceptaTodo").click(function(){
  document.cookie = "track=1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2050 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
  document.cookie = "aceptaCookies=1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2050 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
  $('#nuevaCookies').modal('hide').fadeOut(13000);
})
```

Si va a configurar existen dos opciones o bien que marque la de estadísticas o no. Pero como luego pueden volver a configurar e hecho lo siguiente:

```
$("#guardaConfiguracion" ).click(function() {
  if( $('.estadistica').prop('checked') ) {
      document.cookie = "track=1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2050 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
      document.cookie = "aceptaCookies=1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2050 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
  }else{
      document.cookie = "aceptaCookies=1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2050 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
      document.cookie = "track=1; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1979 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
  }
  $('#nuevaCookies').modal('hide').fadeOut(13000);
});
```

Si le de a si quiere la cookie de analítica, lo guardo en una cookie que se llama `track`y guardo otra cookie como que a aceptado las cookies de la web y así no le muestro más el modal.
Si por lo contrario dice que no quiere analítica, solo guardo la cookie de que a aceptado las cookies y no muestro más el modal.

Si a dado a que si quiere estadística pero luego lo vuelve a configurar y decide que no quiere, la borro con el `else`

Después en el layout he configurado un `if` - `else` para comprobar si existe la cookie de `track` dado que si existe, si quiere analítica.

```
//Check if consent cookie is set
  if(readCookie('track')!="1"){
    window['ga-disable-UA-Id'] = true;
    }
    else  {  
    window['ga-disable-UA-Id'] = false;
    }
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-id');
```

Y con todo esto lo tengo funcionando bien, si algún compañer@ se le ocurre otro modo, estoy abierto a aprender otros métodos mejores.

Lo único que he tenido que quitar el `fade del modal` por que si lo queria abrir de nuevo no funcionaba, me gustaría darle algún efecto de entrada y salida al modal pero no se como.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que esto te sirva, o al menos es parecido a lo que buscas:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836122/how-to-remove-google-analytics-cookies